# What exactly is the "level" parameter used in all OpenGL texture calls?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Does each level contain it's own texture data? How must these be dealt with when copying one texture to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the mipmap level.

Mipmaps are scaled-down textures used instead of the main one when the texture is at an angle or far away, and are used in trilinear filtering. [Obligatory wikipedia link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)

Comment: Thanks. When copying an entire texture from one GLuint "name" to another, I'll need to copy all mipmap levels too?

Comment: How exactly are you copying it, and what is it being used for?

Comment: I'm making a c++ wrapper for a texture, basically. In the copy constructor, I need to copy the image data to a new "name". I'm doing this using glCopyImageSubData, which takes a mipmap level. I assume to have a "complete" copy I'll need to copy all mipmap levels?

Comment: I wouldn't bother implementing a copy constructor on a texture object. It's not very useful. Besides, `glCopyImageSubData` is only available in OpenGL 4.3+, which is pretty new and restricts your target audience. If you want to do it anyway, then yes, you'll have to do it for each mipmap.

Comment: Well, I have thought about the design, and defining proper copies and moves for an OpenGL object seems the most correct to me and conforms to RAII. Also, I'm using QOpenGLFunctions*, so I can check what features are available on particular systems and act based on that. Anyway, Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Ben, I +1 Colonel about not writing a copy ctr. Your concern about design is a good concern. Did you consider to delete the copy ctr / assignment operator instead of implementing them ? Safe and easier.

Comment: @johand. Yes I did. If someone doesn't want an object to be copied, they'd user a pointer or reference. It'd take the same amount of care to use  as any standard library container. You wouldn't pass huge vectors around by value. My design goal was to give them the most correct object, not the safest.

Comment: @Ben Do what you want, but I recommend against wasting time implementing, testing, and documenting a feature that's hardly going to be used by a sane programmer and is only available on [17%](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/statistics_glversion.php) of graphics cards.

Comment: @Ben: It's pretty common for people to accidentally copy objects, for example by forgetting a `&` sign when they declare a method argument. Silently executing a very expensive copy operation is not very user friendly either, IMHO. Good that you're thinking about proper copy behavior, I've seen very interesting bugs when people wrap OpenGL objects in C++ classes, and don't implement (or prevent) copying.

Comment: Another option you could consider is that your primary texture object does not own the texture, but ownership is in a secondary internal object. You reference that internal object in the primary object, and you create an additional reference to the secondary object when the primary object is copied. You could manage the lifetime of the secondary object with reference counting. One downside is that if somebody creates a copy, and then modifies the texture, they modify data that is shared with the original instance. So it won't behave quite like a full copy.